# How to autowrap text in latex?

Tags: text-manipulation, wrap

i m writing one paragraph in which i need to wrap text in a paragraph.

[image]

How can i wrap text "hemorrahagic" to next line or use hyphen two split it into multiline.

Comment: We would need to see the whole paragraph. LaTeX suggests breaking points `hem-or-rhagic` (and Merrim-Webster seems to agree), which should be doable at this place, so please provide more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
he\-morr\-ha\-gic
```

which allows hypenation at the define points or use

```
\begin{sloppypar}
.. your text
\end{sloppypar}
```

Comment: (1) The hyphenation points seem to be wrong: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hemorrhage (2) Since LaTeX should hyphenate the word automatically (the default English suggests some hyphenation points as can be found by `\showhyphens`) it seems to me that there must be a problem elsewhere. Using `sloppypar` without investigating the real causes is very misfortunate.